# Converting output to HTML creates a blank page

Tags: powershell

```
foreach ($computer in $PingCompList){
    if ($computer.STATUS -eq "Responding") 
    {
        invoke-command -AsJob -ComputerName $computer.Address {wuauclt.exe /detectnow}
        invoke-command -AsJob -ComputerName $computer.Address {wuauclt.exe /reportnow}
        write-host -foregroundcolor "Green" "WSUS is now checking in for computer: " + $computer.Address | ConvertTo-Html -Property Id,Name,PSJobTypeName,State,HasMoreData,Location,Command | Out-File -FilePath c:\temp\completed.html
    }
    else{
        Write-host -foregroundcolor "Red" $computer.Address + "is offline" | ConvertTo-Html -Property Id,Name,PSJobTypeName,State,HasMoreData,Location,Command | Out-File -FilePath c:\temp\failed.html
    }   
}
```

I cant see to get this to output to a HTML file. It just returns a blank page. I can see the results on screen but I want a report.

[image]

Comment: the output of `Write-Host` is to the SCREEN, not to the pipeline.  [*grin*] there is nothing in the file since you sent **_nothing_** to the file ...

Comment: It looks like I had the ConvertTo-HTML on the wrong line, it should be piped alongside the command, however, now its only returning the last result.

`invoke-command -AsJob -ComputerName $computer.Address {wuauclt.exe /detectnow} | ConvertTo-Html -Property Id,Name,PSJobTypeName,State,HasMoreData,Location,Command | Out-File -FilePath c:\temp\completed.html`

Comment: Thanks @Lee_Dailey I saw my mistake there shortly before you commented, now I'm just trying to get it to output it all , rather than just the last result. I think my issue lies also with my using Invoke-Ping (a parallel ping function)

Comment: you are quite welcome! [*grin*] ///// take a look at what you have BEFORE you send  it to the pipeline. i suspect you have something other than what you think you have ... [*grin*]